# Compare two specifically formatted strings in .txt file in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a group of targeted data, which is well-formatted and stored in the "target.txt" file.

I want to compare whether or not the output from my code is the same as the result in the "target.txt" file. For example, the content in the "target.txt" file is:

```
#Target result
Fruit 1:
        Name: apple
        Color: green
       
Fruit 2:
        Name: strawberry
        Color: red
```

If the output from my code is:

```
# Current result
Fruit 1:
   Name: apple
        Color: green

Fruit 2:
        Name: strawberry
        Color: red
```

Then, I hope I can get the compared result, which is:

```
Fruit 1:
Compare result: wrong

Fruit 2:
Compare result: correct
```

My question is:

how can I compare these strings, they are well-formatted with specific indentations (it is very important to make sure the indentations are the same).

If I use `==`, I can only compare two strings' contents but not their format.

Does anyone have a hint on how can I compare these kinds of strings?

Thanks!

**Update**:

What I want to compare is whether or not each "Fruit" item in both files is the same, not to compare whether or not the two overall files. I would like to compare "Fruit by Fruit", not line by line (maybe line by line is also OK initially).

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code output also in a file, hash both and compare the hashes. E.g.

```
import hashlib
    
with open("target.txt", "rb") as target:
    first_hash = hashlib.sha256(target.read()).hexdigest()
with open("target_output.txt", "rb") as target_output:
    second_hash = hashlib.sha256(target_output.read()).hexdigest()

if first_hash == second_hash:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a good idea, another question is: I want to compare 'fruit by fruit' (not line by line), for example, I compare whether or not the content in "Fruit 1" is the same in two files, if yes, print 'correct', otherwise 'wrong'. However, this one seems to compare whether or not both whole files are the same. I can also use readline maybe to compare each line in both files, but I actually want to compare each "Fruit". Do you have any idea on this? Thanks. I am not sure if my description is clear enough.

Comment: New question, new post :)

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each "Fruit" with another with readlines. You just have to find the indexes when the first and the second fruit starts. Every item in the list between these indexes have to be the same, so compare them with each other. E.g.:

```
with open("target.txt", "r") as target:
    target = target.readlines()
with open("target_output.txt", "r") as target_output:
    target_output = target_output.readlines()

index_1 = target.index("Fruit 1:\n")
index_2 = target.index("Fruit 2:\n")

for e in range(index_1+1, index_2):
    if not target[e] == target_output[e]:
        print("Compare result: wrong")
        break
else:
    print("Compare result: correct")
```

Comment: Thanks, in this way, there is an only comparison for Fruit 1, Fruit 2. But I have a lot of "Fruits" (e.g., Fruit 1000), so it is not iterable, right?